# NestedScrollview with an EditText inside Cardview inside CoordinatorLayout doesn't fill viewport

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a layout similar to the following in my activity:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingRight="10dip">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/noteBodyEdit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:overScrollMode="always"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This view is included into the CoordinatorLayout as the content view and a standard AppbarLayout with a toolbar is added.

With this code I want the Scrollview and EditText to fill all the content view. However, in this form they end with the wrap_content behavior.

If I change the code and move layout_behavior from CardView to Scrollview, the fillportview issues fixes, but then the content is partially covered by the toolbar.

Any ideas how to solve this with either ways:

1. using behavior on CardView and stretching ScrollView to fill the viewport
2. or, using behavior on ScrollView and making it appear below the toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem is gone after I've updated to the support lib 23.0.0.